# Can't pass parameters to hive script

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have the next hive script:

```
SET LAB_MS_EXT_SCHEME='INTERAL';
set LAB_MS_EXT_SCHEME;
set ${hiveconf:name};
```

So I try to call this script from bash:

```
hive -hiveconf name=HELLLO -f myScript.hql
```

As a result I have the next output:

```
LAB_MS_EXT_SCHEME='INTERAL'
${hiveconf:name} is undefined
```

I will be very thankfull if somebody help me to pass parameters to hive script.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the hiveconf for variable substitution.Please check these link for the answer.

[How to set variables in HIVE scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts)

[Passing parameters in Hive script](https://netezzaadmin.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/passing-parameters-to-hive-scripts/)

[Hive shell inside scripts](https://www.mapr.com/blog/quick-tips-using-hive-shell-inside-scripts#.VWhYsfmqpBc)