# Set variables in hive scripts using command line

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have checked the related thread - [How to set variables in HIVE scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts)

Inside hive the variable is working fine:

```
hive> set hivevar:cal_month_end='2012-01-01';
hive> select ${cal_month_end};
```

But when I run this through command line:

```
$ hive -e "set hivevar:cal_month_end='2012-01-01';select '${cal_month_end}';"
```

It keeps giving me below error:

> Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from
>   an empty string
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:131)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.(Path.java:139)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat$HiveInputSplit.getPath(HiveInputFormat.java:110)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.updateJobWithSplit(MapTask.java:463)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:411)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1469)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally know what's went wrong. The problem is in command line I can't just select something, it needs to from some table. Below is working fine.

```
$ hive -e "set hivevar:cal_month_end='2012-01-01';select * from foo where start_time > '${cal_month_end}' limit 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape few characters. This is working for me.

```
hive -e "set hivevar:cal_month_end=\'2012-01-01\';select '\${cal_month_end}';"
```

Comment: Hi @Durga, I've tried the command you provided, but the error message is exact the same with before.. Any ideas why?

Comment: Which version of hive you are using and what is OS?

Comment: Hive version is Hive 0.13.0-mapr-1501. OS is linux 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the `"` and `'` right.
use this :
`hive -e 'set hivevar:cal_month_end="2012-01-01";select ${cal_month_end};'`

Comment: try running it with `hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console` and paste the output here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set variables as an argument of the hive command:

```
hive --hivevar cal_month_end='2012-01-01' -e "select '${cal_month_end}';"
```

Comment: Yes, I also tried that. But in my system select '${cal_month_end}'; will not work. It will always through a 'Can not create a Path from an empty string' error. I need to use it like this - select * from table1 where a > '${cal_month_end}'; Any idea why is that?