# Escaping dollar signs from hiveql

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm rather new to Hive so be gentle... I have a large table in Hive, and one of the columns has dollar signs in it's values, for example "123$AB". I want to filter the table using this column:

```
select * from foo where bar = "123$AB"
```

Seemed simple but when I executed the query, I got a prompt asking for input: "**Please specify parameters for this query: AB ________**"

A bit of research turned up this:
[How to set variables in HIVE scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts)

I guess Hive is seeing the dollar sign and thinking I want to input a variable or something. OK, so we need to escape the dollar sign.

I tried the following:

```
select * from foo where bar = "123\$AB"
select * from foo where bar = "123\\$AB"
select * from foo where bar = '123$AB'
select * from foo where bar = '123\$AB'
select * from foo where bar = '123\\$AB'
```

but I keep getting the same prompt. It just won't recognize '$' as a character. **How do I escape the '$'?**

For now I am doing the following:

```
select * from foo where substr(bar,1,3) = '123'
```

which works fine for now but I still want to know how to escape special characters. Thanks!

EDIT: Workaround available - see comments!

EDIT 2: To the left of the query editor is a "Settings" tab, and at the bottom of the settings tab is "**OPTIONS**: Enable parameterization". I didn't realize what this was until now. I should have **unchecked** this, which would have solved my problem. However, the problem still exists; if there was a situation where I wanted to use a parameter variable, as well as a character string containing a dollar sign.

Comment: I wonder if two backslashes are needed.  Sometimes that helps.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the suggestion but I tried one, two, three, and four back and forward slashes and it still didn't work :(

Comment: It may not be satisfying but you can use regular expressions:  `foo rlike '^123[$]AB$'`.

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue with Hive CLI nor with Beeline (V1.1.0-cdh5.5.2) - which version are you using?

Comment: Another workaround could be `=concat('123$','AB')` so that the dollar sign is not followed by any alphanum character, and should not reasonably be mistaken for a parameter to be replaced...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I am on Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.5.0. Perhaps updating to 5.5.2 will fix the issue... And thanks for the concat suggestion, it worked!

Comment: Don't think such a minor upgrade would make a difference, might be an obscure config flag that is not set the same way in your cluster and on ours. Anyway, could you edit your question so that it shows "*[Workaround available - see comments]"* or sthg similar?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter original post has been edited!

Answer (score 0):

you can try using back tilde (`) instead of double quotes, the one below Esc key.

```
select * from foo where bar = `123$AB`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess \$\ instead of $ does the job