# Set variables in HIVE query

Tags: hadoop, hive, quantile

I am trying to follow the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts) to set a variable in my Hive query. Assuming I've the following file in hdfs:

### **/home/hduser/test/hr.txt**

```
Berg,12000
Faviet,9000
Chen,8200
Urman,7800
Sciarra,7700
Popp,6900
Paino,8790
```

I then created my schema on top of the data as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (lname STRING, salary INT) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/home/hduser/test/';
```

I want to create 4 tiles for the table but I don't want to hardcode the number of tiles and instead want to pass it in as a variable. My code is below:

```
SET q1=select ceiling(count(*)/2) from employees;
SELECT lname,
       salary,
       NTILE(${hiveconf:q1}) OVER (
                      ORDER BY salary DESC) AS quartile
FROM employees;
```

However, this throws an error:

**FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentTypeException: Number of tiles must be an int expression**

I tried to use quotes when calling the variable, as in `'${hiveconf:q1}'`, but that didn't seem to help. If I hardcode the number of tiles (which I am trying to avoid), the workflow will go something like this:

```
SELECT lname,
       salary,
       NTILE(4) OVER (
                      ORDER BY salary DESC) AS quartile
FROM employees;
```

which yields

```
Berg    12000   1
Faviet  9000    1
Paino   8790    2
Chen    8200    2
Urman   7800    3
Sciarra 7700    3
Popp    6900    4
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Try using single quotes around the `select...` clause when _setting_ the variable.  I googled around a lot and the Hive variable capability is pretty limited -- basically macros.  I would consider rethinking how you could accomplish your objective using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

When there isn't a documented way one can use documented features to provide a clean enough hack :)

Here's my attempt, using dfs commands from hive, shell commands from hive, the source-command and what not. I guess it might not work out of the box with queries through Hiveserver2. I would be glad if there were a prettier way

Let's go

**Basic setup**

```
SET EMPLOYEE_TABLE_LOCATION=/home/hduser/test/;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (lname STRING, salary INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '${hiveconf:EMPLOYEE_TABLE_LOCATION}';

SET PATH_TO_SETTINGS_FILE=hdfs:/tmp/query_to_setting;
SET FILENAME_ON_LOCAL_FS=query_to_setting.sql;
```

**Generate a file in hdfs**

with content `"SET q1=<the-query-result>;"`

```
CREATE TABLE query_to_setting_table
LOCATION '${hiveconf:PATH_TO_SETTINGS_FILE}'
AS
SELECT concat('SET q1=', ceiling(count(*)/2),'\;') from employees;
```

**Source in the generated file as any sql-file.**

First put the file to local fs since 'source' only operates on local disk...

```
dfs -get ${hiveconf:PATH_TO_SETTINGS_FILE}/000000_0 ${hiveconf:FILENAME_ON_LOCAL_FS};
source ${hiveconf:FILENAME_ON_LOCAL_FS};
```

**Try the setting**

```
hive> SET q1;
q1=4
```

**Use the setting in a query**

```
hive > SELECT lname,
          salary,
          NTILE( ${hiveconf:q1}) OVER (
                      ORDER BY salary DESC) AS quartile
       FROM employees;
OK
Berg    12000   1
Faviet  9000    1
Paino   8790    2
Chen    8200    2
Urman   7800    3
Sciarra 7700    3
Popp    6900    4
```

Optional cleanup

```
!rm ${hiveconf:FILENAME_ON_LOCAL_FS};
DROP TABLE query_to_setting_table;
```