# What is the difference between -hivevar and -hiveconf?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

From hive -h  :

```
--hiveconf <property=value>   Use value for given property
--hivevar <key=value>         Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                  commands. e.g. --hivevar A=B
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I didn't quite feel like the examples from the documentation were adequate, so here's my attempt at an answer.

In the beginning there was only `--hiveconf` and variable substitution didn't exist.

The `--hiveconf` option allowed users to set [Hive configuration values](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties) from the command line and that was it.  All Hive configuration values are stored under the `hiveconf` namespace, i.e. `hiveconf:mapred.reduce.tasks`.  These values allowed you to control things like the number of mappers and reducers, if status messages should be displayed, and if the script should continue on errors.

Later, [variable substitution was added](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1096).  This meant you could now use variables in queries with the `${...}` syntax.  However, the only variables you could set from the command line were under the `hiveconf` namespace using `--hiveconf`, so that's where users put their variables.

Putting your personal variables under the Hive configuration namespace probably won't break anything, but it's also not good form.  Later, [it was suggested](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2020) that a `hivevar` namespace be added specifically for user variables which could also be defined at the command line using `--hivevar`.  This meant a cleaner separation between Hive configuration values and user defined variables.

**In summary:**
The `hiveconf` namespace and `--hiveconf` should be used to set Hive configuration values.
The `hivevar` namespace and `--hivevar` should be used to define user variables.
Setting user variables under the `hiveconf` namespace probably won't break anything, but isn't recommended.

Comment: I actually figured it out a long time ago ,but nice answer ,Thanks!

Comment: I figured you probably had, but I decided to submit another answer for future readers, just in case. =]

Answer (score 15):

@Llama has explained it in detailed, along with that both type of variables are accessed differently.

The `--hivevar` variables are accessed using `${var-name}`, while the `--hiveconf` are accessed `${hiveconf:var-name}` inside hive.

e.g. Below examples access variable and print it's value in hive.

**hivevar:**

```
hive --hivevar a='this is a' -e '!echo ${a};'
```

output:`this is a`

**hiveconf:**

```
hive --hiveconf a='this is a' -e '!echo ${hiveconf:a};'
```

output:`this is a`

Answer (score 5):

We can also use them at the beginning of the script as:

**hiveconf:**

```
SET this_dt = CURRENT_DATE;
select ${hiveconf:this_dt};
```

**hivevar:**

```
set hivevar:cur_dt=current_date;
select ${hivevar:cur_dt};
```

Comment: Hi, could you add hivevar in a separate config.hql and them import the to main hql script ?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this for the difference

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution

There are three namespaces for variables – hiveconf, system, and env. ([Custom variables](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2020) can also be created in a separate namespace with the define or hivevar option in Hive 0.8.0 and later releases.)

Answer (score 1):

I found some differences between hiveconf and hivevar with hive/beeline circa 2023.

```
hive> set param1= 123; -- does not work
hive> set hiveconf:param1 = 123; -- does not work
hive> set hivevar:param1 = 123; -- works
hive> select ${hivevar:param1}; -- shows 123
```

In the first 2 cases, the error is:

```
Cannot modify parame1 at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime (state=42000,code=1)
```

The difference apparently come from the the system hive/beeline conf:

```
hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist  
OR
hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append
```

In addition, as mentioned by another post, hiveconf vars are meant to be used for system-wide hive config, while hivevar is used for user config.
[How to set variables in HIVE scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

No difference except the namespace. `hiveconf` and `hivevar` are different namespaces. `hivevar` namespace was added just to separate configuration properties namespace and Hive variables namespace. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2020 for more information.