# Not able to pass parameters to hql from sh file

Tags: shell, hive

## I have a .sh file from which I am passing values to .hql, but its giving me errors

```
sm=1
XXXXX=""
while read -r line
do
   name="$line"
   XXXXX="hive$name(${XXXX[$sm]%?})"
   echo $XXXXX
   hive -hiveconf var1=$XXXXX -hiveconf var2=/user/cloudera/project -hiveconf var3=$name -f test1.hql
   sm=$((sm + 1))
done < "$filename"


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${hiveconf:var1}
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
location ${hiveconf:var2/hiveconf:var3};
```

*Please note that $XXXXX is creating a tablename with schema after reading from the file and some logic. When I echo it, there is no problem, but problem comes in .hql file. Error is somewhat like below :

```
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

FAILED: ParseException line 2:4 cannot recognize input near 'ROW' 'FORMAT' 'DELIMITED' in column type
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.

Comment: Variable XXXXX contains "hivecategories(category_id int,category_department_id int,category_name string)"... but when I echo it on hql, it isn;t passing the whole value... just "hivecategories(category_id " and that is causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to quote variable:

```
hive -hiveconf var1="$XXXXX"
```

All such variables should be quoted

Use this command inside script to check value passed:

```
! echo "${hiveconf:var1}";
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate to above is using hivevar:

```
sm=1
XXXXX=""
while read -r line
do
   name="$line"
   XXXXX="hive$name(${XXXX[$sm]%?})"
   echo "${XXXXX}"
   hive -hivevar var1=${XXXXX} -hivevar var2="/user/cloudera/project" -hivevar var3=${name} -f test1.hql
   sm=$((sm + 1))
done < "$filename"


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${var1}
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
location ${var2/var3};
```

Also here is a link for a read on the difference between hiveconf and hivevar in case the curiosity bug bites :)

[What is the difference between -hivevar and -hiveconf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997008/what-is-the-difference-between-hivevar-and-hiveconf)