# Hive Variables in Where Clause

Tags: hive

SELECT * FROM Tablename
WHERE 1=1
(AND COL1=VALUE1 AND COL2=VALUE2)         --->$(VAR)

SELECT * FROM Tablename
WHERE 1=1
$(VAR)

This is possible in Hive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set variables in HIVE scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
set hivevar:var1='and col1=10 and col2=10';

! echo "select * from table where 1=1 ${hivevar:var1}";
select ${hivevar:var1}


[prjai@lnx0689 prvys]$ hive -f test.hql
"select * from table where 1=1 'and col1=10 and col2=10'"
OK
and col1=10 and col2=10
Time taken: 2.152 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

For more details on how to use hivevar and hiveconf, refer 
[https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997008/what-is-the-difference-between-hivevar-and-hiveconf)

[What is the difference between -hivevar and -hiveconf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997008/what-is-the-difference-between-hivevar-and-hiveconf)

Answer (score 0):

Set hive variable variable first.

```
 set hivevar:queryPortion='and col1=value1 and col2=value2';
```

After that just retrieve it in your query

```
 select * from table where 1=1 ${queryPortion}
```