# How to use params/properties flag values when executing hive job on google dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to execute a hive job in google dataproc using following gcloud command:

**gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=msm-test-cluster --file hive.sql --properties=[bucket1=abcd]**

**gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=msm-test-cluster --file hive.sql --params=[bucket1=abcd]**

But none of the 2 above commands is able to set 'bucket1' variable to 'x' variable .

The hive script is as follows:

```
set x=${bucket1};
set x;
drop table T1;
create external table T1( column1 bigint, column2 float, column3 int) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'gs://${hiveconf:x}/output/prod';
```

But the variable 'x' is unable to take 'bucket1' variable which i passed in the gcloud command.

How do i do it? Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both examples should work with minor tweaks.

- In `cloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=msm-test-cluster --file hive.sql --properties bucket1=abcd`, you can access variable as `${bucket1}`
- In `gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=msm-test-cluster --file hive.sql --params bucket1=abcd`, you can access variable as `${hivevar:bucket1}`

Easy way to test this, is to submit a script like this to dump all variables:

`gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster msm-test-cluster -e "set;" --properties foo=bar --params bar=baz`

The output should contain:

```
| foo=bar    
| hivevar:bar=baz
```

Related question:
[How to set variables in HIVE scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636)