# Deletion of partitions older than 30 days in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have Hive table partitioned based on date yyyy-mm-dd. I want to run a script everyday that can delete all the partitions older than 30 days but in this case I don't want to pass the date. I want it to take system date and delete the partitions older than 30 days.

Comment: Is your hive table managed or external table?

Comment: What do you use to run your hive scripts? UNIX, ADF etc?

Comment: It's managed orc table and I have written scripts in hql. I can use linux or unix scripts that is not a problem. Can you help me out

Comment: Please share what attempts you've done already

Comment: Tried one script but it deletes all the partition older than current date. I tried to give pass the value 30 but it throws error ->                             
 hive --hivevar today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") -e \
> 'alter table local_db.mytable drop partition (day<date '\''${hivevar:today}'\'')'

Comment: Well, yeah. You're not passing the date of 30 days ago

Comment: You just missed the 30 days ago. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use Linux/ Unix to set the variable for the DROP PARTITION date and use it in the ALTER TABLE statement.

Here is an example

```
CREATE TABLE ramesh.test
(col1 STRING, 
 col2 STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (partition_date date);

INSERT INTO TABLE ramesh.test PARTITION (partition_date='2017-10-01') VALUES ('key1', 'val1');
INSERT INTO TABLE ramesh.test PARTITION (partition_date='2017-10-02') VALUES ('key2', 'val2');
INSERT INTO TABLE ramesh.test PARTITION (partition_date='2017-11-01') VALUES ('key3', 'val3');
```

```
hive --hivevar var_drop_date="$(date -d "30 days ago" +"%Y-%m-%d")" -e 'ALTER TABLE ramesh.test DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (partition_date <= date "${hivevar:var_drop_date}")'
```

This drops the 2 partitions from 30 days ago and leaves the one within 30 days.

Let me know whether it works for you. I used CDH for testing this.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. I also tried on CDH, it solved my problem. Can you please explain (date -d "30 days ago" +"%Y-%m-%d")  and I am confused when to use --hivevar, --hiveconf and --hiveenv

Comment: date command with "30 days ago" gives you the sys date - 30 days. Please see this for hivevar/ conf - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts

Comment: Got it. Thanks Ramesh

Comment: @Priyanka - you are welcome. You may want to mark it as the answer here as the solution has worked.