# SQL query to show only non-duplicated row and duplicated row only from recent date

Tags: sql, hive

So I have two tables (let's say x and y). Most of the data from both table are duplicated but there are some rows that are different. I insert whole data from those two tables into a new table (let's say table_mixed). There's one column that indicate table's date e.g. 20190307 for x and 20190308 for y So, for any duplicated rows, there will be a date column that is different.

```
num        Code     col1 col2 col3.....  import_date    file_date   
-------- ---------  -----------------   ----------   ----------
01         AA       ......                20190308          20190307      
01         AA       ......                20190308          20190308      
02         AA       ......                20190308          20190307      
03         BB       ......                20190308          20190308
```

What I am trying to do is, I want to query a data such that, show a non-duplicated row from both table and for any duplicated row, shows only a row with recent date.

I have done some finding and I have tried this:

```
select *,max(file_date) over (partition by stx_import_date) max_date 
from table_mixed;
```

where file_date is a date that tell the different date from each table and every row from both table has the same import_date.

```
num        Code     col1 col2 col3......  import_date    file_date     max_date 
-------- ---------         ------------     ----------  ----------
01         AA       ......                20190308        20190307     20190308
01         AA       ......                20190308        20190308     20190308
02         AA       ......                20190308        20190307     20190307
03         BB       ......                20190308        20190308     20190308
```

The result from this query show every row (including all duplicated row) and add another column (max_date) that show only the recent file_date for each of the row. But I want the result to show only what I mentioned above and no additional column (max_date).

This is the result that I am looking for:

```
num        Code     col1 col2 col3...  import_date  file_date   
-------- ---------    ------------    ----------   --------   
01         AA       ......            20190308        20190308      
02         AA       ......            20190308        20190307      
03         BB       ......            20190308        20190308
```

Thank you

P.S Not only column num, code and import date that need to be duplicated but also other columns that I ..... So, what I mean duplicated row >> every column except file_date (which I have 10+ columns)

P.S.2 I edited the example so that you guy want get me wrong. There're other columns (like col1, col2, col3 and so on) that also used. How should I use partitioned by in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [row_number](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) window function.

- Do partition on **`num,code,import_date..etc`** columns.
- Order by on **`file_date`** desc

***Sample query:***

```
Select * from (
select *,row_number() over (partition by num,code,stx_import_date order by file_date desc) row_number
from table_mixed)t
where t.row_number = 1;
```

Comment: I also found something related to this row_number function. The actual data that I am working with is not just num,code, stx_import_date but every other column. So, do I have to partition by every column(like 15-20 columns)

Comment: like are there any efficient way than typing almost all of the column to be partitioned?

Comment: @Jamiewp, Possible other way would be using Hive variables and define variable value as your column names `num,code,stx_import_date..etc` and reuse them, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts, apart from this i don't think there another way instead we need to mention all column names in `partition by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to care about the `num` column and only want the most recent data.  You can do this with your mixed table as:

```
select tm.*
from (select tm.*,
             row_number() over (partition by num, code, . . . order by file_date desc) as seqnum
      from table_mixed
     ) tm
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  If the file dates are the same, then an arbitrary row will be chosen.

This may be more efficient to do when you create the mixed table.  You can just do:

```
select y.*
from y
union all
select x.*
from x left join
     y
     on x.num = y.num and
        x.code = y.code and
        . . .
where y.num is null;
```

This returns all rows from `y` (the more recent) along with any non-matching rows from `x` (and assumes none of the column values are `NULL`).

Comment: The change in num column is just for the example. Actually the non-duplicated row I mentioned can be any of the column that different.

Comment: Thank you for helping. The point is that I have too many columns to be used to check for duplicate. Are there any more efficient way other than typing all column except the file_data?

Comment: @Jamiewp . . . No, there is not in Hive unless you start using wildcards for columns.  And 15 columns or so is not very much to type.  You've typed a lot more in asking the question here.

Comment: Sorry, this might be more than I asked but what I aim to do is that, I have many files which each file have its own schema so, one might have id, code, num another might have name, address, etc. So, if there is a query that no need to specify any column name separately, it would be good(I will need to integrate with Python script later on)

Comment: @Jamiewp . . . That is not the question that you asked.  Changing this question would invalidate the answers of people who have tried to help you.  So, I would recommend that you ask another question and be as clear as you can be regarding the data your have and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe grouping by the MAX() of whatever date field will be the differentiator?

```
;WITH get_max_dt AS (
    SELECT TM.[num]
    ,   TM.[Code]
    ,   TM.[import_date]
    ,   MAX(TM.[file_date]) AS [file_date]
    FROM table_mixed AS TM
    GROUP BY TM.[num],TM.[Code],TM.[import_date]

)
SELECT *
FROM get_max_dt
```

Output:

```
num  Code  import_date  file_date
01   AA    20190308     20190308
02   AA    20190308     20190307
03   BB    20190308     20190308
```

Comment: I edited the question. The differentiator is every other 10+ columns except the file_date column

Comment: @Jamiewp . . .And ???  Aggregation should work for what you want (as well as `row_number()` in the other answers).