# Hive- how to get the derive column names and use it in the same query?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to run the below query :

```
select [every_column],count(*) from <table> group by [every_column] having count(*) >1
```

But column names should be derived in the same query. I believe show columns in  would list down the column names separated by new line. But I need to use it in one query to retrieve the result.
Appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`shell sed`** to search the `newlines(\n)` and replace with `comma(,)`.

- Assign the comma separated column names to a `hive variable`, use the variable name in your hive query.

References for [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) and [set hive variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using subqueries or even CTE? Maybe this helps you find your answer:

```
select outer.col1,
       outer.col2,
       outer.col3,
       outer.col4,
       outer.col5,
       outer.col6, count(*) as cnt
from (
        select <some logic> as col1,
               <some logic> as col2,
               <some logic> as col3,
               <some logic> as col4,
               <some logic> as col5,
               <some logic> as col6
        from innerTable
)outer
group by outer.col1,
       outer.col2,
       outer.col3,
       outer.col4,
       outer.col5,
       outer.col6
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! But I am looking to get the column names in the subquery and then use the column names in the outer query