# How to use hive variable substitution rightly

Tags: hiveql, beeline, hivecli

When I'm using variable substitution in hive, I meet some errors, but I need your help.

My code:

```
set hievar:b='on t1.id=t2.id where t2.id is null';
select * from t_old as t1 full outer join t_new as t2 ${b};
```

when I run this code in hive shell, it give me some error about `${b}`.

I also try this:

```
set hivevar:c='select * from t_old as t1 full outer join t_new as t2 on t1.id=t2.id where t2.id is null';
${c};
```

It gives me the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set variables in HIVE scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Fix `hivevar` namespace name (in your code it is `hievar`) and remove quotes, because they are also passed as is in Hive.

Example:

```
set hivevar:b=where 1=1; --without quotes
select 1 ${hivevar:b}; --you can do without hivevar: as in your example
```

Result:

```
OK
1
Time taken: 0.129 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Second example:

```
hive> set hivevar:c=select 1 where 1=1;
hive> ${c};
OK
1
Time taken: 0.491 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```