# Delete partition with non-constant value in Hive

Tags: sql, database, hive, database-partitioning

I want to delete a partition in Hive with its value being in another table or being created by a function on-the-fly. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE
    table_1
DROP IF EXISTS
    PARTITION (dt = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, 63),'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyyMMdd'))
```

Or something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE
    table_1
DROP IF EXISTS
    PARTITION (dt = SELECT date FROM table_2 LIMIT 1))
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
cannot recognize input near 'FROM_UNIXTIME' '(' 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' in constant
```

If I replace the whole call to `FROM_UNIXTIME()` with a fixed number, it works fine. Is there a way to do this witouth hard-coding the value of the partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hive-cli doesn't support that, We need to use **Shell script** for that

***Sample Script:***

```
#!/bin/bash
my_value=$(hive -S -e "select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, 63),'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyyMMdd')")
echo $my_value
hive -S -e "alter table table_1 drop partition (dt = $my_value)"
```

For more details refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/60309/working-with-variables-in-hive-hive-shell-and-beel.html) links about hive variables.