# How to forloop a value in a Hive table to get the expected output

Tags: bash, for-loop, hadoop, hive

I have a list of owners and table has the file details with file owners, size, atime, mtime,...file full path.
Suppose I want to know how many files the owner owns from table, with the help of for loop, is it possible?

I tried the below with `where` clause but it seems I am missing something.

```
for i in `cat owner_name.txt`;do hive -e "use <DB name>;select * from <table name> where owner="$i"";done limit 10 >> single_use.log
```

here `owner_name.txt` has list of owner-names which are matching with the owner column inside the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set variables in HIVE scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts)

Comment: Try `owner='$i'"`, and put the limit within the query, not after `done`